# Printing table with large number of rows creates page break issue on safari for desktop and Ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, page-break-inside

If there are many rows in a table, then the row breaks the content. The issue is not happening on Chrome. I have tried the code sandbox demo for the same Please refer [[https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-james-mphv85]](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-james-mphv85)(CodeSandbox). I need Help if anyone knows how to handle page breaks in Safari.

I have tried page-break-inside: avoid property but still, it is not working for Safari

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).